# What percentages should be expected for an SVM to be accurate?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, svm

In an assignment I am currently doing, I trained an SVM
with my training set and got the results

```
accuracy:   0.983
true  positive rate: 0.544
false positive rate: 0.006
true  negative rate: 0.439
false negative rate: 0.012
```

Testing the results of the validation set shows me

```
 accuracy:   0.979
 true  positive rate: 0.816
 false positive rate: 0.003
 true  negative rate: 0.164
 false negative rate: 0.018
```

The accuracy is high for both which i assume is a good thing,
but for the true positive etc, what values should I be aiming for
and what do they actually mean?

Comment: What data are you using? How "good" your accuracy is depends completely on the difficulty of the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the meaning of the four results:

**True positiv**: the result was supposed to be positiv (=class 1) and the predicted result by the model was positiv (=class 1) -> High values of this are good!

**False positive**: the result was supposed to be negativ (=class 0) but the model returned positiv result (=class 1). In fact, the model confused the two classes, which is bad. Thus, lower numbers are better.

**True negative**: the result was supposed to be negative (=class 0) and the model‘s answer was negative (=class 0). This is good, larger numbers are better.

**False negative**: the result was supposed to be positive (=class 1) but the model returned negative (=class 0). This is bad, lower numbers are better.

All four are percentages. All together they should sum up to 1 (=100%). The true negative and true positive rate together sum up to the accuracy.

Machine learning is very data specific, so no one will be able to tell, which performance to expect, without having tested your specific data, with multiple algorithms and parameters. It would be nice if such a formula would exist, which would tell one what algorithm and parameters to use, but in fact the only way known up till today, is to test different setups against a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

While Marcus' answer explains very clearly what are True/False Positive/Negatives. It may be a bit misleading as the question asked for their respective **rates**, which is not the same thing.

These however generate from the True/False Positive/Negatives, so you should read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) article on wikipedia explaining what these rates exactly are.

Where TP = True Positive, FN = False Negative, etc.